# Python not operating with super long list

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Hi i have a list with 15205 variables inside, im trying to find the relative frequency of each variable but python don't react with such a big size.
if i try len(list) it works, but max(list) gives me '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int', and set(list) gives me 'type' object is not utterable. If i try to work with it as a data frame it gives me TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Plus, if i use a small sample of the list everything works fine.

Can anyone explain me why does this happen and how can i work it out?

thanks

Comment: The problem is not the length of the list, 15000 is small, but that it contains both integers and lists, so it can't be sorted.

Comment: It sounds like your list is a mix of `int` and other `list` values, like `[[1,2], 3]`, for instance. Computing the maximum of this list would require comparing `[1,2]` to `3`.

Comment: You're getting that error with `max()` because it doesn't work on a list with multiple object types. `set()` will not work if the list contains list elements, since sets can't contain lists, which are unhashable. If you want to count it, convert all inner lists to and mutable types to an immutable representation (eg: tuples). `collections.Counter` is a good quick way to do this.

Comment: Please update your question with some example code which demonstrates the issue you are seeing.

Comment: If all you care about is getting the max even with sublists, then a simple way would be `max(flatten(lst))`, where `lst` is your list and  `flatten` is one of the many flattening functions posted for flattening lists.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you shouldn't name your list 'list', since this is a reserved word in Python referring to the type. This is the origin of your 'set(list)' error.

As for the other error, at least one of the items in your list appears to be itself a list, and you can't compare the magnitude of a list and an integer.